# how do I read a shapefile into r in a format that leaflet can use

Tags: r, leaflet, shapefile

I'm trying to do some leaflet plots with San Francisco precinct shapefiles. It's worked before, but the precincts and their shapefiles have been updated & I can't seem to load them in a form that leaflet recognizes.

```
If I use st_read, the shapefile seems to load okay, but leaflet objects.  If I do

sfprecincts <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer = "SF_DOE_PREC_2022_07_18_pg"), I get this warning message:
```

Warning messages:
1: In OGRSpatialRef(dsn, layer, morphFromESRI = morphFromESRI, dumpSRS = dumpSRS,  :
Discarded ellps WGS 84 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
2: In OGRSpatialRef(dsn, layer, morphFromESRI = morphFromESRI, dumpSRS = dumpSRS,  :
Discarded datum WGS_1984 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
3: In showSRID(wkt2, "PROJ") :
Discarded ellps WGS 84 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
4: In showSRID(wkt2, "PROJ") :
Discarded datum World Geodetic System 1984 in Proj4 definition

Comment: This is just a warning thrown by GDAL (rgdal). It should work using that with leaflet.

Comment: Leaflet "worked" but I get the map that shows multiple world maps side by side.  I think somehow it's not being able to see what the projection is.